# Inserting a node in Binary search tree in python

Tags: python, insert, binary-search-tree

I know the basic working code for inserting a node in BST. But I expected this function to add a node at the right end of BST (because its value is the maximum in that tree), but it doesn't work and I wanna know the reason. I tried debugging it but I'm still not clear why it's behaving this way.

```
def putValueInBST(root, val):  # assuming the val = 7 which is max of all the existing node values in BST
    if root is None:
        root = Node(val)
    elif val > root.data:
        putValueInBST(root.right, val)
    else:
        putValueInBST(root.left, val)
```

This code below behaves as expected.

```
def put_val_manually(r, val):
    r.right.right = Node(val)
```

Aren't both of the above functions kinda similar, since they are adding the node at the end of the BST?
(of course in the `put_val_manually()` function, I am doing it directly.)

The full code is here: https://i.ibb.co/yf2YTYy/code.png

Comment: `root = Node(val)`: this updates the parameter `root`. This cannot work. Parameters are *always* passed by value in python. So basically this statement is useless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @qouify . I guess i will have to read more about how python deals with the function parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Try to return the node

```
def putValueInBST(root, val):  # assuming the val = 7 which is max of all the existing node values in BST
    if root is None:
        return Node(val)
    elif val > root.data:
        root.right=putValueInBST(root.right, val)
    else:
        root.left=putValueInBST(root.left, val)

root=putValueInBST(root,val)
```

This code works

Comment: You need a `return root` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Kirushikesh i know the correct code but my question was different :)